# Carregar um json em um DropDownList Yii2

Tags: json, dropdownlist, yii2

Recentemente migrei para o framework YII 2. E estou com uma pequena dúvida: Tenho um json que preciso popular um DropDownList.
O arquivo Json:

```
[
{"codigo": "05", "descricao" : "Administrador"},
{"codigo": "10", "descricao" : "Diretor"},
{"codigo": "16", "descricao" : "Presidente"},
{"codigo": "22", "descricao" : "Sócio"},
{"codigo": "29", "descricao" : "Sócio ou Acionista Incapaz ou Relativamente Incapaz (exceto menor)"},
{"codigo": "30", "descricao" : "Sócio ou Acionista Menor (assistido/representado)"},
{"codigo": "37", "descricao" : "Sócio Pessoa Jurídica Domiciliado no Exterior"},
{"codigo": "38", "descricao" : "Sócio Pessoa Física Residente ou Domiciliado no Exterior"} 
]
```

Como vocês podem notar, tenho um 'código' e uma 'descrição'. Preciso carregar esse dropDownlist com esse *json*, onde ele se encontra em um diretório da minha aplicação ('web/js/json/exemplo.json').

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utiliza a função [decode()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-helpers-basejson#decode()-detail) para converter a String json para um Array, e depois usar o ArrayHelper para mapear o array para `"chave" => "valor"`(que é o formato aceito pelo select).

```
<?php 
$json = [
{"codigo": "05", "descricao" : "Administrador"},
{"codigo": "10", "descricao" : "Diretor"},
{"codigo": "16", "descricao" : "Presidente"},
{"codigo": "22", "descricao" : "Sócio"},
{"codigo": "29", "descricao" : "Sócio ou Acionista Incapaz ou Relativamente Incapaz (exceto menor)"},
{"codigo": "30", "descricao" : "Sócio ou Acionista Menor (assistido/representado)"},
{"codigo": "37", "descricao" : "Sócio Pessoa Jurídica Domiciliado no Exterior"},
{"codigo": "38", "descricao" : "Sócio Pessoa Física Residente ou Domiciliado no Exterior"} 
];
echo Html::activeDropDownList($model, 'atributo',
      ArrayHelper::map(yii\helpers\Json::decode($json), 'codigo', 'descricao')); 
?>
```